# Modifying a term in lucene

Tags: lucene.net

Let’s assume I have an index structured as below

```
    name | species | color
    -----+---------+------
    max  | cat     | grey
    sam  | dog     | brown
    luy  | cat     | white
    ...  | ...     | ...
    ...  | ...     | ...
    poe  | dog     | blond
    joe  | cat     | red
    pam  | dog     | brown
```

The species and color fields are tokenized, indexed and stored.

Now let’s assume that I want to change the term cat to feline and dog to canine.

From what I have been reading, I would have to delete each Document(row) and re-add it with the new term.
Since the original cat and dog terms are Indexed, Tokenized and Stored, it seems like there should be a way to update just the terms cat and dog to their new titles.

Is there already a way to do this? Did  I just miss it?

Comment: lucene .net or java? please re-tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt that field values can be changed without re-adding the documents. However, based on your hypothetical scenario, you may want to look into [searching for *synonyms*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=lucene+synonyms) of the search terms. For example, you could leave "cat" and "dog" in the index, but expand users' queries to also search for "feline" and "canine" respectively.

`"cat"` becomes `"cat" AND "feline"`

`"dog"` becomes `"dog" AND "canine"`

This functionality may come as a delight to your users if they are not aware of which terminology you have chosen in the index.